# How to get rid of InvokeEndpoint logs in CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I have millions of logs in CloudWatch of the following type:

```
"POST /invocations HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "AHC/2.0"
```

I am assuming these logs are generated when InvokeEndpoint is called for a particular Sagemaker Container. Is there a way how can I prevent these logs from reaching my CloudWatch log group ?

I followed a similar discussion here : https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit/issues/83, but didn't find the correct solution.

Any tips/pointers would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this the basic default logging level and is indicative of the POST invocations requests. There are ways to increase the log level but not decrease in your use case. You can export these logs to 3rd party services and filter logs if needed.